# Calculating $f(x)$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, functional-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial satisfying the relation $$f(x)f(y)=f(x)+f(y)+f(xy)-2; \forall x,y \in \Bbb R;\\ f(0)\ne1, f(4)=65,$$

By plugging $x=y=1$, we get two values of $f(1)=1,2$. But now which is the correct value? Similar when we do it for $x=0$, $f(0)=1,2$ and following the question $f(0)=2$. But as it is a non-constant polynomial $f(1)=1$, is this argument correct? We can easily calculate all the values of $f(x)$ as we did for $x=0,1$. We can also plug $y=\frac{1}{x}$ but now how should we calculate $f(x)$. Because we have two values each for $f(1),f(2),f(3)....$so on. But which is the correct one and what's the reason?

Comment: Your argument that $f(2)=1$ is wrong. A non-constant polynomial can take the same value twice. $f(x)=(2x-1)^2$ is non-constant, but $f(0)=f(1).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $p(x)=f(x)-1$ then we have $$p(x)p(y)= p(xy)$$ and $p(0)\ne 0$ and $p(4)=64$.

Then $p(1)=1$ (plug $x=0$ and $y=1$) and $p(0)=1$ (plug $x=y=0$). Also $p(2)^2 = p(4) = 64 \implies p(2) = \pm 8$.

Let $p(x) = ax^n+...$ and $a\ne 0$.

- If $p(2)=8$ then we get $8p(x) = p(2x)$ for all $x$ and thus $8ax^n + ...= a2^nx^n+...\implies \boxed{n=3}$...
- If $p(2)=-8$ then we get $-8p(x) = p(2x)$ for all $x$ and thus $-8ax^n + ...= a2^nx^n+...$ and thus no solution.

Comment: Then $p(x)=x^3$?

Comment: The fact that $64=4^3$ seems not to matter. $p(0)\ne0$ already nails $p$ beyond existence

Comment: @Aqua, Can you please explain after that step if $p(2)=8....$?

Comment: Just put $y=2$ ...

Comment: @Aqua, Yes, sorry missed it. But a really great solution.

Comment: @Aqua, now assuming p(2)=8,we will have to derive a cubic function? Or the function doesn't exist?

Comment: It's coming $f(x) =x^3+\frac{x^2} {8} -\frac{3x} {4} +2$ @Blue

Comment: Yes, but now you have to check if it really works. :(  @L

Comment: @Aqua, $f(0),f(4)$ is satisfying but $f(1)$ is something awkard.

Answer (score 4):

Let $c=f(0)\ne1$ and plug in $y=0$ to arrive at
$$ c f(x)=f(x)+2c-2 $$
and simplify.

Comment: non-constant polynomial?

Comment: Your point? @Community

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I am getting from this $f(x)=2$

Comment: But it is given non-constant, am I missing something?

Comment: @Joe, yes again $f(y)=2$ so it has no solution as answered by Aqua above

Comment: Right, the only $f$ either has $f(y)$ is constant or $f(0)=1.$ That is the point. But your initial question appears to imply the answerer missed that condition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, the answerer has given directly $f(x)=1+x^3$ but it's not correct as $f(0)=1$, so only remains is no solution

Comment: But this answer avoids all that, showing the functional equation and $f(0)\neq 1$ is enough to show $f(x)=2$ is constant and $f(4)\neq 65.$ @Community

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that means the question itself is wrong, right?

Comment: @Learner depends on what was the original question.